# Failing to authenticate HttpClient via pfx certificate

Tags: c#, ssl, tls1.2, client-certificates

For the past days I've been struggling with implementing a client side REST-API communication requiring a certificate to authenticate itself.

I have no control over the server side but I have been provided with the **PFX certificate** as well as a password for said certificate.

I have been able to successfully connect to the API through Firefox and while I doubt Chrome doesn't work, as I've clicked "ignore" on the certificate the first time I get a response code of 403... but I have been unable to be queried for the certificate again by Chrome.

The point being that the certificate works for sure. Yet I am unable to replicate this in C# using any to me known method.

My first attempt was to simply use HttpClientHandler like so

```cs
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2("<path>", "<password>"));
handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
handler.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false;
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback += (m, x, p, b) =>  true;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
var response = client.GetAsync("<api-url>");
```

Whereby response always comes with a 403 forbidden response code. As in, the same code I get when not providing a certificate through browsers.

After a few hours on google, I also found a code snipped that claimed this only works if the certificate itself is installed and went with the following approach of providing the certificate:

```cs
private static X509Certificate2 FindCert(X509Store store, string thumbprint)
{
    foreach (var cert in store.Certificates)
        if (cert.Thumbprint.Equals(thumbprint,
            StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            return cert;
    return null;
}

var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(FindCert(store, "<cert-thumbprint>"));
// other properties are same as before.
```

Once again to no avail. After everything involving `HttpClient` failed, I tried my luck using `SslStream` instead and manually solve my problem:

```cs
var client = new TcpClient();
await client.ConnectAsync("<url-host>", 443);
var sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), true, (_, __, ___, ____) => true);

X509Certificate2Collection certificates = new X509Certificate2Collection(
    new X509Certificate2("<path>", "<password>")
    );

await sslStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync("<url-host>",
    certificates,
    SslProtocols.Tls12,
    false);

var writer = new StreamWriter(sslStream);
writer.NewLine = "\r\n";

await writer.WriteLineAsync("GET <url-path> HTTP/1.1");
await writer.WriteLineAsync("<more headers taken from firefox's successful connection");
await writer.WriteLineAsync();  // empty line for end of headers
await writer.FlushAsync();

var reader = new StreamReader(sslStream);
string response = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
```

As you might have guessed, response simply read `"403 forbidden"` again.
On a note of interest. `sslStream.IsMutuallyAuthenticated`, `sslStream.IsAuthenticated`, `sslStream.IsEncrypted` and `sslStream.IsSigned` are all true.

I am at my wits end and any help is much appreciated!

Comment: TLS is done before the REQUEST is sent.  If TLS fails than not request is sent and you will not get a response.  Therefore your issue is not TLS since you are getting a status.  Is your URL HTTP or HTTPS?  HTTP does not use TLS and will fail if you send TLS (encryption).

Comment: Does the API require any other form of authentication apart from the cert? I agree it looks as if TLS is working, just the server is requiring further authentication.

Comment: @jdweng accessing the same URL in a browser (firefox) works so a simple GET request should still yield a result other than 403.

Comment: @Charlieface yes but the absence of the username/password credentials would yield a different error message (401 – Unauthorized). From my testing with browsers it seems that the certificate comes first (403 on fail), followed by credentials (401 on fail) followed by the actual REST API request.

Comment: If you install Fiddler you can intercept the requests with it. You will need to install the Fiddler intercept certificate, and turn on "Decrypt HTTPS". Then can you show a screenshot of the headers of a valid request via browser and also the failing one via `HttpClient`?

Comment: The default HTTP headers are different in c# than in firefox.  Most likely there is something different with the header.  Using a sniffer like Fiddler will show difference.   I would capture headers using HTTP (not encrypted) for comparison between firefox and c#.  Then once the http matches in c# and firefox go back to https.

Comment: @jdweng this is a bit of a late response but to reiterate, headers are not the problem. HTTP is not an option as the port isn't open. I can send the request from two browsers and compare the headers with no significant difference between working and not working. The idea that headers are the reason is why I tried the manual method (`SslStream` instead of `HttpClient`) in the first place. Since `AuthenticateAsClient` is a method provided by `SslStream` I feel fairly certain it's part of the SSL handshake.

Comment: First, you are getting a response which means SSL/TTLS is working.  If SSL/TLS is failing you would not get a response.  So issue must be with the request.  There are difference between the request.  You said "NO SIGNIFICANT DIFFERENCES".  So what you think is not significant is the cause of the issue.

Comment: Stupid question but did you add the cert to the cert store on the machine? .Net uses that to find the correct cert when needed.  If you're in Docker, you'll need to load the cert into the containers cert store before you run the service up.